# IDEA's maven webapp project settings

Tags: java, maven, spring-mvc, intellij-idea

I want to create webapp project using IDEA IDE, but I am confused with basic web setting. I have got standart maven-webapp project archetype with `web.xml` in `src/main/webapp`, with some spring code in `src/main/java`; Path for `web.xml` I have specified in `Deployment Descriptors` path. But what have I to specify in `Web Resource Directories` and `Source Roots`? Project Settings=> Modules => WEB. I am new to IDEA, everything works under eclipse, but not in IDEA. By the way, I need `Servlets 3.0` specification, as I want to start `Spring MVC` based application using Java-based configuration: by extending `AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer`, not mapping via xml

Comment: What version of Intellij do you use ? With the community version you can't make a web project.

Comment: @Mr_Thorynque as I see it is IntelJ IDEA 2016.2.3

Comment: Community or Ultimate ? https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/#section=windows

Comment: @Mr_Thorynque  Ultimate. 30-days free version